# UPDATE table using CTE

Tags: t-sql, update, cte

I wanted to update the ranks of my table `Performance` and I found this solution, but I do not understand why this SQL code works:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT AllTimeRank, r = RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY Distance ORDER BY TimeInSeconds) 
    FROM dbo.Performance
)
UPDATE cte 
SET AllTimeRank = r FROM cte;
```

The statement says `UPDATE CTE` but in fact, it really updates the table (`dbo.Performance`).

**Can someone explain me this *magic*?**

The following statement seems to do exactly the same:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT Id, r = RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY Distance ORDER BY TimeInSeconds)
     FROM dbo.Performance
)
UPDATE dbo.Performance 
SET AllTimeRank = r 
FROM cte INNER JOIN dbo.Performance p ON p.Id = cte.Id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No magic. CTE in this case is an updatable view.

Updatable and Insertable Views:

- [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#updatable-views)
- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/view-updatability.html)
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html)
- [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0052325.html)
- [Teradata](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/73CtDAp6xBsTDbgLnifMKA/024moVMYKm6FsiFPvoeenw)

> *The following statement seems to do exactly the same:*

In general - no. Simply imagine that `id` is not unique.

> *Is the first option better?*

Two queries with different (general) logic cannot be compared. - [akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)

Comment: @akina, in my case then, which approach do you suggest? I need to update the ranks of my table, as illustrated in my question.